# Possible to clone a bitlocked hard drive?

Tags: bitlocker, clone

My laptop m2 drive is failing after five years

It is bitlocked

Is it possible to clone it?

The idea is to mount an external adapter to a new m2 drive, and to boot from a USB to clone it.

Comment: Does `manage-bde -status` report it as using hardware or software encryption?

Comment: what have you tried?